# Netbeans 11.2 on Ubuntu 18.04 - cannot access java.lang Fatal Error: Unable to find package java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath

Tags: java, netbeans

I have a problem when using netbeans 11.2 in ubuntu 18.04.
This is my machine:

```
dzil@jarvis:~$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.6" 2020-01-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.6+10-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu118.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.6+10-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu118.04.1, mixed mode, sharing)

dzil@jarvis:~$ cat /etc/issue.net 
Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
```

For the netbeans installer, I got them from the official web: [Official For Linux](https://www-us.apache.org/dist/netbeans/netbeans/11.2/Apache-NetBeans-11.2-bin-linux-x64.sh)
Evertything is running well.
For testingm create a class in a java project (Java with Maven):

```
package com.mycompany.mavenproject1;

public class Main {

}
```

I got error: cannot access java.lang Fatal Error: Unable to find package java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to reapply the JSDK home path. To do so go to File -> Project Structure -> Platform Settings -> SDKs and reapply the JSDK home path.